# Response time vs. throughput to check whether need upgrade Heroku?

Tags: heroku

`Heroku` show response time (msec), throughput (request / min, ok, failed). How to know I need upgrade their service? Number of failed request will increase if more user is coming?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(disclaimer: I work on the team that provides the data for that page in dashboard).

Capacity planning isn't an easy problem, and it's especially hard without some more details. Taking into consideration the response time and the number of requests per some interval is *part* of it, but not typically the whole story.

First, let me ask: What are your goals? Do you have a target latency in mind? Do you expect to double the number of requests you're receiving due to a launch, or some press? What other systems does your application rely on (e.g. PostgresQL, another HTTP based API, other databases, etc)? What are the characteristics of the programming language and software you are using? Do you have any other measurements besides what the dashboard is showing you that give you more insight into where time is being spent, and how saturated your resources are? Have you done any benchmarking, or load testing that gives you a theoretical top of line that your app can manage?

Second, let's create a simple scenario to demonstrate why some of those questions are necessary.

I have a small web application that is deployed to 1 server, and the application does not support concurrency, which means I can only handle 1 request at a time. If it takes 500ms to respond to a request, than the best the application can *ever* do is serve 2 requests a second. If that 500ms isn't stable, say, it varies between 400ms and 600ms, the application can't even *always* do 2 requests per second, but it'll probably average out to 2r/s.

If we can reduce the time it takes to serve a request, then, we can do *more than* 2 requests per second. Or, if there's no way possible to reduce the amount of time it takes to serve a request, than, the only thing we can do is increase the number of requests we can handle at the same time. If, instead we went from being able to handle 1 request at a time (let's call these web-workers), to 4 requests at a time, then suddenly I can handle *8* requests per second, provided that the latency per request stays the same.

On Heroku, there are two ways to increase the "web-workers". The first is to run more dynos. The second is to configure your application's web server concurrency settings appropriately. For some setups on Heroku, the buildpack will provide defaults that work well for most cases.

So, now that we're on the same page with the basic theory behind capacity, let's talk about how you can better figure out what *your's* is.

Your median response time peeked at 3s in the time period you're showing. That's an anomaly (at least for this time period), and while I'm curious to understand what happened, I think we should focus on figuring out *why* the P95 (i.e. 95% of your requests were served *faster* than that value) is so high, and what those errors are.

On the dashboard, there's a chart called "Events." Do the charts show any [H* errors](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes)? If they do, that's going to provide you a bit more insight into those. If *not*, you're going to need to rely on your [application logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging). If you, at a terminal, watch your logs for a little while using `heroku logs -t -a <your application>` (or your logging addon if you have one) you'll see request logs that the router produces. If you see a log with `status=5XX` (where XX is 00, or something else), *hopefully*, your application is also spitting out errors around the same time that give you insight into why the error is happening. Perhaps it's simply a database error of some sort (maybe a timeout error? Not sure).

Which leads me to my next suggestion. We often see database queries taking a long time, which leads to slower response times. In some cases, these queries can be sped up with an index, or be rewritten to do make less queries/do less work. But, in order to gain any insight into that problem we've gotta measure things, and look at some of the database metrics. If you're using Heroku Postgres, there's a [dashboard](https://data.heroku.com) already that can provide some information. There's also the `pg:diagnose` command, and other suggestions on the [Postgres Devcenter page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#performance-analytics) that might give you more insight into if your database might be causing your slow down.

I'd also suggest, if your application isn't emitting its own database related timing data already, that you do so. It's easy to add to each of your database calls, and find the ones that are taking the most time, which you can then focus on. (translate the following into your language)

`startTime = time.now()
results = someDD.Query()
print "someDB query took: ", time.now() - startTime, "seconds to complete"`

That's super simple, and also *extremely* informative. View the logs with the "logs -t" command (or if you're using a logging addon, through that).

Finally, I'll make one other suggestion. It's not always the case that you can speed up database calls, or "do less work" in request handlers, and if you find that to be the case, there are alternative ideas that require some restructuring the way in which your application works. The [Worker Dynos, Background Jobs and Queueing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) article on [Devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/) explains the architecture we recommend in these cases, and offers a bit of direction.

I *hope* this was useful for you, and gave you some guidance as to next steps. We *do* have an [Autoscaling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#autoscaling) product for higher tier dynos, but it works best for larger, and more predictable workloads. I'd guess that with the amount of requests you're doing now, you're best bet is just understanding a bit more about what's going on and taking steps to fix it.

Good luck!